# Event / Gesture Recognizer that fire before Value Changed fired on UISlider - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I look for an event that would fire on touch down, and fire BEFORE "Value Changed".

I've tried to use Touch Down from Inteface Builder, but if user tap at the "Thumb" the "Value Changed" event is fired ealier.

[image: StoryBoards events]

Comment: It's seem's like a property of slider to call value change first and it work's around it wherelse if you try out with different component you will have different stuff. No exact answer I got for it. Still I will look into it and If I came across anything I will post out. Also as button is to be touch inside or outside similarly slider is gng to detect value change firstly. At end, no appropriate reason for it!

Comment: Also slider's main use is reality for value change purpose and I don't see why u need touch inside or outside for?!! What do you want achieve ?

Comment: Basically something like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/gmrijgfzisraod9/t8e75kry.png, And I would like to have some "inertia" to make "thumb" as button, if user change value less than say: 10% of the slider.

Comment: So simply at value change do will a check for value user leave's slider and then perform your task according. Example :    NSLog(@"Value: %f",[_slider value]); this would show you value been changed If you put it in a method connected to slider(via valueChange). So when condition is true then bang you gotcha' !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fix it as below :

- Remove the target for valueChanged from the xib.
- Add the target for valueChanged in the touchDown method.
- Remove the target in TouchUp method.